# Python. Проблема с компиляцией в .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller, python-3.7

Есть одна проблема - не открывается файл **.exe** (ну точнее, просто открывается и сразу закрывается) после компиляции из **.py**, где использовалась библиотека **pygame** и модуль **sys**.

*Ниже - код основного файла игры:*

```py
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from cowboy import Cowboy
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():

    # Инициализирует игру и создает объект экрана.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height)
    )
    pygame.display.set_caption("Cowboy Attack")

    # Создание ковбоя
    cowboy = Cowboy(ai_settings, screen)

    # Создание группы для хранения пуль.
    bullets = Group()

    # Назначение цвета фона
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    # Запуск основного цикла игры.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, cowboy, bullets)
        cowboy.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, cowboy, bullets)
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)

run_game()
```

*процесс компиляции в **cmd:***

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2018. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack

C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack>pyinstaller cowboy_attack.py
105 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
105 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
105 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
107 INFO: wrote C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\cowboy_attack.spec
109 INFO: UPX is not available.
111 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\sanek\\Desktop\\Cowboy_Attack',
 'C:\\Users\\sanek\\Desktop\\Cowboy_Attack']
111 INFO: checking Analysis
112 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
112 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
116 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
119 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5366 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5370 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\sanek\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
6477 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6490 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\cowboy_attack.py
7050 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
7128 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
7129 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\sanek\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
9357 INFO: Loading module hooks...
9357 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
9360 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
9496 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
9966 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
10045 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
10437 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
10439 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygame.py"...
10440 WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found!
10441 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
10442 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
10443 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
10444 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
10510 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
10542 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
10550 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
10563 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
16439 INFO: Looking for eggs
16439 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\sanek\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
16440 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
16450 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\build\cowboy_attack\warn-cowboy_attack.txt
16581 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\build\cowboy_attack\xref-cowboy_attack.html
16609 INFO: checking PYZ
16610 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
16611 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\build\cowboy_attack\PYZ-00.pyz
17881 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\build\cowboy_attack\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
17915 INFO: checking PKG
17915 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
17917 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
17954 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
17956 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\sanek\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
17957 INFO: checking EXE
17957 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
17957 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
17958 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\sanek\Desktop\Cowboy_Attack\build\cowboy_attack\cowboy_attack.exe
17970 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
17976 INFO: checking COLLECT
17976 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
17977 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
18472 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

*скриншоты директорий после компиляции:*

[image: скриншоты директорий после компиляции]

_папка dist: _[image: папка dist]

**P.S. Вот ссылки на файлы игры:**

1. [ZIP Архив (удалите .exe)](https://github.com/alkir202/PythonEM/blob/testing_branch/Course/Part_2/Project1_Alien_Invasion/Cowboy_Attack_(my_version)/Cowboy_Attack.zip.exe?raw=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рабочем каталоге, куда поместил ваши модули:

```
pyinstaller -F -w cowboy_attack.py
```

Вот протокол, гляньте, может что-то найдете кроме различий версий:

---

```
D:\_Qt\__Qt>cd Cowboy

D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy>pyinstaller -F -w cowboy_attack.py
1919 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
1929 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
1929 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
1939 INFO: wrote D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\cowboy_attack.spec
1939 INFO: UPX is not available.
1969 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\Cowboy', 'D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\Cowboy']
1979 INFO: checking Analysis
1979 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1979 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1997 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
2098 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
23065 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
23254 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
24894 INFO: Caching module hooks...
25011 INFO: Analyzing D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\cowboy_attack.py
30645 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
39382 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
39402 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site
yInstaller\\fake-modules'
57727 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
93307 INFO: Loading module hooks...
93307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
93377 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
93697 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
93927 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
94287 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
94291 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-OpenGL.py"...
99085 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
102846 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
104122 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
104124 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
104124 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygame.py"...
104134 WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found!
104134 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
106074 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
107961 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...
108224 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
111347 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
111439 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
115099 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
115139 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
115139 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
115623 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
117152 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
117192 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
117252 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
117262 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
117362 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
125425 INFO: Looking for eggs
125425 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
125435 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
125505 INFO: Warnings written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\build\cowboy_attack\warn-cowboy_attack.txt
126708 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\build\cowboy_attack\xref-cowboy_attack.html
127026 INFO: checking PYZ
127028 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
127032 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\build\cowboy_attack\PYZ-00.pyz
134701 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\build\cowboy_attack\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
135021 INFO: checking PKG
135021 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
135031 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
203917 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
203947 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootlo
-64bit\runw.exe
203947 INFO: checking EXE
203957 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
203957 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
203991 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy\dist\cowboy_attack.exe
204261 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

D:\_Qt\__Qt\Cowboy>
```

---

Перебросил папку с картинками в каталог `dist`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Запустил `cowboy_attack.exe` .  Все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, даже не думал, что дело в ссылках!